# Hardhat console log a string and variable in same statement

Tags: solidity, console.log, hardhat

Is there a way I can log a string and a `bytes` variable in the same statement using `hardhat/console.sol`? Or at least have them print on the same line?

In the [Hardhat docs](https://hardhat.org/console-log) it shows that you can add string arguments:

```
console.log("Changing owner from %s to %s", currentOwner, newOwner)
```

but is there a way to do this for other kinds of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overload of `log` function of `hardhat/console.sol` contract for `(string,bytes,bytes)`, but there is one for:

```
function log(string memory p0, string memory p1, string memory p2) internal view {
    _sendLogPayload(abi.encodeWithSignature("log(string,string,string)", p0, p1, p2));
}
```

Which means, you can use it like this:

```
console.log("your format string %s %s", string(yourBytesVariable1), string(yourBytesVariable2));
```